# Can you have electric current without a circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, maxwell-equations

I'm trying to understand Maxwell's 4th equation, which is

$$ \bigtriangledown \times B = \mu_0j + \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial E}{\partial t} $$

I understand that $\bigtriangledown \times B$ corresponds to curl of the magnetic vector field. I know $\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$ is another 3d vector representing the change in a vector field over time.

But what I'm trying to understand, is $j$. Is it just change in charge density over time? Can a stray electron moving through space be understood to have current, or does it only have meaning in circuits? And if the latter, what precisely is required for a circuit?

Essentially, what is meant by "current"?

Comment: There are bulk conductors and plasmas with vortex currents etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the equation j can be zero it usually comes in a circuit, but a electron beam also results in current, and charge with phases through an area is a current, but a stray e would be a very, vera short time current!

Comment: What exactly does current mean then?

Answer (score 0):

The current is given by

$$I=\frac{dq}{dt}$$

i.e, the amount of charge flowing through a certain region per unit time. Current density

$$j = \frac{I}{A}$$

or the amount of charge per unit time per unit area.

> Can a stray electron moving through space be understood to have current, or does it only have meaning in circuits?

It is a charge moving through space per unit time, so yes. It can be considered a current.

> And if the latter, what precisely is required for a circuit?

An electric circuit is any path for which transmitting an electric current is possible. An electric circuit must include a device that gives an EMF (electromotive force), or energy for the charged particles constituting the current to flow.

Comment: "Current" has two meanings in the context of electrical circuits.  One meaning is a phenomenon: current is the motion of electrical charge. Second is the physical quantity,  defined as in the other answers.  So any motion of charge is a current.  And can be associated with the physical quantity current (or intensity of the current).

Comment: How does $I = \frac{dq}{dt}$ work? In a circuit, isn't $\frac{dq}{dt}$ equal to 0, since just as much charge is entering any given region of the circuit as is leaving?

Comment: Sorry. I was surprised because you were interpreting Maxwell's equations but are having a hard time understanding simple current. I cannot explain this any more simpler. Please click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current) which explains the concept of current in depth and starting from the beginning. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> But what I'm trying to understand, is j. Is it just change in charge
> density over time?

No. If the density of charge is constant for example, it doesn't mean that current is zero. Only its divergence is zero.  $$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla\mathbf{.j} = 0$$

> Essentially, what is meant by "current"?

Current means a flow of charge carriers, electrons in a conductor, electrons or holes in a semiconductor, ions in a solution and so on.

The density of current (in the $x$ direction for example) can be understood as a density over a spacetime volume, where $\Delta x$ is replaced by $\Delta t$:
$$j_x = \frac{\Delta q}{\Delta t\Delta y\Delta z}$$

Density of charge carriers on the other hand can be regarded as a density of current through time:
$$\rho = \frac{\Delta q}{\Delta x\Delta y\Delta z}$$